# tangent line equation help me

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble finding the solution to find an equation of the tangent line to the graph $$y=x^4 - \ln x + 1$$ at the point $(1,2)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. In particular, can you find the derivative of the function? The slope of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of the tangent line must equal the derivative $y'(1)$ of the curve given by

$$y=x^4-\ln x+1$$

at the point $(1,2)$.  The derivative is given by

$$\begin{align}
y'(1)&=\left(\left.4x^3-\frac1x\right)\right|_{x=1}\\\\
&=3
\end{align}$$

And, the line passes through $(1,2)$ with slope $3$ is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=3x-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

(1) What is the slope of the line that is tangent to that graph at x=1?

A: We take the derivative of the function and substitute x=1. The derivative = $4x^3 - \frac{1}{x}$

For $x=1$ The value is: $4 - 1 = 3$

Thus, the slope is 3, and the line passes through the point (1,2)

(2) How does this determine a line?

A: Using point slope form, the line is: $y - 2 = 3(x-1)$

Which is equal to: $y = 3x -1$

Comment: Thank you. Do i eliminate the ln when finding the solution?

Comment: The ln disappears when calculating the derivative because the derivative of ln(x) = 1/x. Once we use this to find the slope, we have a slope and a point, and all we need afterwards is an equation of a line.